# AngularJS : Using angular-ui-router with electron

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, electron

I'm trying to integrate angular, angular-ui-router and [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to build a desktop app which is also a single page application. I'm unable to get a proper route configuration using angular-ui-router without messing up the file paths.

Below is my routes config.

```
/*
 * Fetch angular template for given page
 */
var getTemplate = function (page) {
    return ['getView', function (getView) {
        return getView.get(page);
    }];
};
var skeletonStateConfig = function () {
    var config = {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        controller: 'site',
        views: {
            s: {
                templateProvider: getTemplate('p/out')
            }
        }
    };
    return config;
};

/*
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Configure root page states
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

var pageStateConfig = function (page, url, controller) {

    var config = {
        views: {
            'p@': {
                templateProvider: getTemplate(page)
            }
        }
    };
    if (angular.isUndefined(url)) {
        url = page;
    }
    if (url !== '') {
        config.url = '/' + url;
    }

    if (angular.isDefined(controller)) {
        /* Specific controller is allocated for this route */
        config.views['p@'].controller = controller + ' as PageCtrl';
    } else if (controller !== false) {
        /* Replace hyphens in page name to underscore to get angular controller */
        config.views['p@'].controller = page.replace(/-/g, '_') + ' as PageCtrl';
        /* oc lazy load resolve */
        config.resolve = {
            oc: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'oc',
                    files: [page]
                });
            }]
        };
    }
    return config;
};

/*
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 | States configuration
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

$stateProvider
    .state('p', skeletonStateConfig())
    .state('p.login', pageStateConfig('login', 'login', 'login'));
/*
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Redirects and Otherwise
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Use $urlRouterProvider to configure any redirects (when)
 | and invalid urls (otherwise)
 |
 */

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

To summarise, `p` is the initial state which is abstract. It loads the skeleton of the app. `p.login` state is the state for the home page and it loads the content for the home page.

When the app is opened, it triggers `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')` and p.login state is loaded.

**But, on refresh I get the following error.
GET file:///login net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Navigated to data:text/html,chromewebdata**

On removing `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')`, the app always loads the index.html file. So, how to do I goto `p.login` state without messing up the paths?

Comment: you can't use `html5Mode` with the `file://` protocol, a server is required.  see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Disabling html5Mode did the trick.

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login') doesn't work after the app is packaged using `electron-packager`. Tested on mac. The app works fine when using `electron .`